# ¿recibir campo con otro format diferente al que tengo en la BD'

Tags: php, mysql

estoy usando mysql.

tengo un campo que por defecto aplica este valor `date_format(current_timestamp(),'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%S %p')`

y necesito traer solo el año desde php.

estoy usando esta funcion para traer solo el año:

```
$fechabd=(29/02/2020 09:40:43 AM)
$fecha=date("Y", strtotime($value["fecha_hora"]));
```

pero el resultado obtenido es otro: `1970`.

como puedo formatear correctamente esa fecha para obtener los valores que quiero.

Comment: Según entiendo en tu DB tienes la fecha con formato `DD/MM/AAAA` y deseas obtener solo el año, correcto?

Comment: puedo hacer con un SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el caso que expones puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` y usar `format` para obtener sólo el año:

```
$fechabd="29/02/2020 09:40:43 AM";
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s A', $fechabd);
echo $fecha->format('Y');
```

No obstante, te recomendaría no formatear la fecha en el `SELECT`, sino traerla tal cual y luego usar `format` en la salida, como hacemos aquí: `echo $fecha->format('Y');`, el problema es que como lo estás haciendo, estarías formateando dos veces sin necesidad. Mejor traer la fecha virgen como la tienes guardada.

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, solo que estoy reutilizando la fecha de ese campo, para ponerlas en un option, la habia formateado desde la bd para no hacerlo desde el servidor porque no habia visto la necesidad de reutilzar ese campo, pero igual me sirvió, gracias.

Comment: @CRIS19N desde el `SELECT` también puedes formatear para obtener solamente el año, pero generalmente si se va a reutilizar la fecha con diferentes formatos es mejor traerla sin formato y aplicar el formato en la vista.

Comment: hay alguna funcion de javascript para aplicar un formato similar o jquery?

Comment: @CRIS19N ECMA Script tiene una API de Internacionalización que puedes usar ([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/5587982))  o puedes usar la biblioteca [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com) que es muy ligera y muy fácil de usar.

Comment: como pueda formatear la fecha con SELECT y obtener el año si ya esta almacenada en ese orden (d/m/Y H:i:s A)?

Comment: @CRIS19N, MySQL tiene una [función `(YEAR)`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-year/) con la cual puedes sacar el año del una fecha, el uso sería simplemente: `SELECT YEAR(laColumnaFecha) AS y FROM laTabal`

Comment: el resultado que tengo es NULL, un listado de NULL.

Comment: SELECT YEAR('29/03/2000 10:06:55 AM'); ese es un ejemplo, pero el resultado es NULL.

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE(fecha_registro,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%S %p') as list_fecha FROM fecha; este select los ordena empezando por año, puedo agregar un select para sacar el Y? como una subconsulta

Comment: me estaba complicando, un poco, lo que hice fue dejar la fecha en formato '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%S %p' ya depues hago los select que necesite, solo que como no habia visto la necesidad de usar ese campo por eso la habia dejado ya formateada por defecto.

Comment: @CRIS19N no entiendo mucho en qué sentido se complica. Sigo te interesa el año puedes usar `YEAR` en el SELECT y si te interesa ordenarlo por fecha simplemente usas ORDER BY fecha_registro

Answer (score 0):

Obtienes el campo fecha de la BD completo, sin formatear, y luego mediante PHP cambias el formato:

```
$fechaBD = "2020/08/07 21:10:15";//Esta sería la fecha de tu BD 
$fecha = date("Y", strtotime($fechaBD));
echo $fecha;//Salida: 2020
```

[Documentación PHP date().](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)